# Select sum based on value of other column

Tags: sql, db2, case, common-table-expression, db2-luw

I have a table with values like

```
ID | CODE | QUANTITY
====================
1  | 2    | 20
2  | 2    | 40
3  | 5    | 10
4  | 6    | 15
5  | 5    | 20
6  | 6    | 50
7  | 6    | 10
8  | 7    | 20
9  | 8    | 100
```

I have a requirement to get the sum of all quantities with "CODE" = 2. However, if the sum is 0
then return the sum of all quantities where "CODE" in (5,6). The idea is to ignore all other codes except 2, 5, and 6, with 2 as the first preference for sum.

I have tried this

```
WITH CTE AS(
SELECT
    SUM(CASE WHEN CODE = '2' THEN QUANTITY ELSE 0 END) AS QUANTITY1,
    SUM(CASE WHEN CODE IN ('5', '6') THEN QUANTITY ELSE 0 END) AS QUANTITY2
FROM TABLE1
)
SELECT CASE
            WHEN QUANTITY1 <> 0 THEN QUANTITY1
            ELSE QUANTITY2
        END
FROM CTE
```

It does work but I feel it can be improved and can be done in minimum steps. How can I improve it?

Edit1: The value of QUANTITY column can be 0 in TABLE1
Edit2: [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/90bf1d/1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the sum of quantities with `CODE = '2'` use `ELSE 0` in the `CASE` expression and `NULLIF()`, so that the result is `NULL` even if the sum is `0`:

```
SELECT COALESCE(
         NULLIF(SUM(CASE WHEN CODE = '2' THEN QUANTITY ELSE 0 END), 0),
         SUM(CASE WHEN CODE IN ('5', '6') THEN QUANTITY END)
       )
FROM TABLE1
```

You can use `ELSE` for quantities with `CODE IN ('5', '6')` too:

```
SELECT COALESCE(
         NULLIF(SUM(CASE WHEN CODE = '2' THEN QUANTITY ELSE 0 END), 0),
         SUM(CASE WHEN CODE IN ('5', '6') THEN QUANTITY ELSE 0 END)
       )
FROM TABLE1
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9b690f5fa3ea7ba2cd772c2850218f1f).

Answer (score 1):

If quantity is always greater than `0` in the underlying table, you can use `COALESCE()`:

```
SELECT COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN CODE = '2' THEN QUANTITY END) AS QUANTITY1,
                SUM(CASE WHEN CODE IN ('5', '6') THEN QUANTITY END),
                0) AS QUANTITY2
FROM TABLE1
```

Comment: Quantity can be 0. This doesn't seem to work if the sum of all quantities with CODE =2 is 0.

Comment: I guess it can be resolved by adding a non-zero check.
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/08b697/1

Comment: @bluelurker . . . I wasn't clear on the specific conditions.  It should be that quantity is always greater than zero.  With a name like `quantity` that seems like a reasonable assumption.